# Write optimized code which takes following two list of dictionaries as input and gives output as final_result.I have solved it but I want to optimized

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, list-comprehension

Inputs:

```
list1 = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}]

list2 = [{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]
```

Challange1:
If the item_type is present in list2 then that should take the priority.

expected result:

```
final_result = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]
```

Challange2:
It should merge list1 and list2 based on unique item_type and keep the higher 'value' dictionary.

expected result:

```
final_result = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]
.
```

I have solved both the challenges but I want to optimized this code using list comprehensive, lambda .. please help me...

this is my code

Challange1:

```
final_result = []
list1 = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}]
list2 = [{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[i]['item_type'] == list2[j]['item_type']:
            if list1[i]['item_type'] < list2[j]['item_type']:
                final_result.append(list1[i])
            else:
                final_result.append(list2[j])
            break
    else:
        final_result.append(list1[i])
print(final_result)
```

Challange2:

```
final_result = []
list1 = [{'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},{'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},{'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}]
list2 = [{'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},{'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[i]['item_type'] == list2[j]['item_type']:
            if list1[i]['value'] > list2[j]['value']:
                final_result.append(list1[i])
            else:
                final_result.append(list2[j])
            break
    else:
        final_result.append(list1[i])
print(final_result)
```

Comment: This would be better placed on Code Review.  Out of scope for this site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to optimized my code which is Challange1 and Challange2 ... In short my code is not optimized I have used for loops ... rather than this I want to use lambda function and list Comprehensions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use list (or other) comprehension.

From Python 3.7, dictionaries are officially ordered. You can (1) concatenate the lists and sort the items if necessary, (2) put the items into a dictionary with `item_type` as their keys, and (3) convert values in the dictionary back to the list, to get the desired results.

**Challange1:**

```py
final_result = [*{item['item_type']: item for item in list1 + list2}.values()]
```

**Challange2:**

```py
final_result = [*{item['item_type']: item for item in sorted(list1 + list2, key=lambda item: (item['item_type'], item['value']))}.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

According the stated information in the question.

The first challenge is to union the two lists with a priority to the second list. A quick solution can be:

```
list1 = [
    {'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},
    {'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},
    {'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}
]

list2 = [
    {'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},
    {'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}
]

final_result = [
    item for item in list1
    if item['item_type'] not in 
    [item['item_type'] for item in list2]
] + list2

print(final_result)
```

The second challenge is to union the two lists with a priority to the `value`. A quick solution can be:

```
list1 = [
    {'item_type':1,'value':55, 'title':'abc'},
    {'item_type':2,'value':43, 'title':'def'},
    {'item_type':3,'value':35, 'title':'ghi'}
]

list2 = [
    {'item_type':2,'value':13, 'title':'jkl'},
    {'item_type':3,'value':85, 'title':'mno'}
]

isNotIn = lambda item, L: len(
    [el['item_type'] for el in L 
    if item['item_type'] == el['item_type']]
) == 0
isHigher = lambda item, L: len(
    [el['item_type'] for el in L 
    if item['item_type'] == el['item_type'] and 
    item['value'] > el['value']]
) > 0

final_result = [el for el in list1 if (isNotIn(el, list2) or isHigher(el, list2))] + \
    [el for el in list2 if (isNotIn(el, list1) or isHigher(el, list1))]
print(final_result)
```